# changing a variable depending on time in R ODE solver

Tags: r, function, ode, differential-equations

I have a model that has a differential equation in it, that I'm solving using odesolver in R. One of the parameters that you give to the ode function is times. Is there a way that you can change another variable depending on what time it is in the solver (e.g. for seasonal changes). What I'd like to do is something like the below, where ODETIME is the variable for times in ODE.

```
function1 <- function(r, y, x) {   
  z <- x[which(x$time = ODETIME),2]
  list(- r * y * z)
}
N    <- 10
r    <- runif(N, 15, 20)
yini <- runif(N, 1, 40)
vals <- rep(1:5, 22)
times <- 0:10
x <- data.frame(time = rep(times, 10), vals)
out <- ode(y = yini, parms = NULL, times = times, func = function1)
```

Comment: You mean an `event`? https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/deSolve/versions/1.7/topics/events

Comment: That looks like it'll do the job!